# Compiler not showing warning messages for explicit casts

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

I have recently downloaded the MinGw compiler and for some reason it does not display and warning messages when I should be doing a explicit casts.

For example:

```
double x=9.97;
int y=x;
```

This seems to be ok with the compiler. I was just wondering do I need to install some other package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no cast required when assigning a `double` to an `int`. The decimal part is simply truncated. If you want warnings on this you can use `-Wconversion` or `-Wfloat-conversion`.

Comment: I thought that the truncation would cause an error. Thats why I thought you needed a casting operator.

Comment: Sorry I still dont get it. I know in java that if we are converting and there is a loss of information we need a casting operator. So do the new compilers in C just accept it without throwing a warning message?

Comment: C and Java are different languages. Don't compare them. C is a loosely typed language. In C, there is no cast required. And its not just the new C compilers that behave this way. All of them does. And there *is* a way to enable the warning if you need it. Just use `-Wconversion` or `Wfloat-conversion` if you use GCC.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the other answer, a technical explanation about implicit conversion semantics can be found on http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion:

> A finite value of any real floating type can be implicitly converted to any integer type. Except where covered by boolean conversion above, the rules are:
>   - The fractional part is discarded (truncated towards zero).
>      . If the resulting value can be represented by the target type, that value is used
>      . otherwise, the behavior is undefined

Comment: Your quote is helpful, but this is a C question, please to not confuse the OP with link to this C++ site. This site is riddled with imprecisions and errors. eg on the vey page you link to: *`2u - 10; // signed / unsigned, same rank
         // 10 is converted to unsigned, unsigned math is modulo INT_MAX
         // result is 4294967288 of type unsigned int (aka INT_MAX-7)`*

Comment: To be precise the site is about C++ **and** C. I linked to a page specifically about C. Fair enough to point out imprecisions and errors. The site is a wiki though, so I believe you can contribute to it and fix those mistakes to improve it. I'm not affiliated to it at all, but I still find it to be a useful source of information.

Comment: Point well taken. I could invest some time trying to fix the errors I come across on this site, but it is quite overwhelming and I would not touch the C++ pages with a 10-foot pole.